# Trouble summing $\frac{1}{3^i}$ from 1 to n

Tags: summation

$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3^i}\tag{displayed}$

I can't figure this out.  I expanded it: $(\frac {1}{3^1}+\frac{1}{3^2}+...+\frac{1}{3^n})=S$, and I think the technique is to multiply both sides by something and then subtract, but I'm not quite sure how to make everything cancel out.  Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $3$. Then note the left hand side of the resulting equation is $1+S-{1\over 3^n}$. Then solve for $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
Do you know the geometric series?

Comment: @Rokko Nevermind that, I feel the same often enough. If this helped you, you can upvote or accept :)

Answer (score 1):

In geometric progression a(1st term)=1/3 and r=1/3 
so sum= a(r^n -1)/r-1

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format answers using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: +1 As you are a new user and this is your first post! :).

Answer (score 0):

step 1. Multiply the left hand and right hand the equation you post by 1/3. Mark it as b_n(the origin one is a_n)

step 2. calculate a_n - b_n

it is what you want.